# replacing values in dataframe using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

wanted to replace values with "NaN" where percentage is greater than 100, in "ROE" column. Reading csv file. Following is the code, not sure how to assign values in 'missing' dataframe, please help

** ROE column in the dataset contains value like "25.00%", "130.00%", "50.00%". so while comparing, first need to convert values in the float by removing last character.

```
missing = pd.read_csv(local_path + "/Week4/Datasets_Week4/roemissing.csv")
print(missing)

for x in missing["ROE"]:
    y = float(x[:-1])
    if y>100:
        print(x.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
missing['ROE'] = missing['ROE'].str[:-1].astype(int)
missing.loc[missing.ROE > 100, 'ROE'] = np.nan
```

`missing.ROE > 100` will select the rows in which the `ROE` value is greater than `100`. 'ROE' is the column name where you need to replace values of the selected rows.

All rows with `ROE` value greater than `100` are selected and then sets the value to `NaN` to the selected rows in the column `ROE`.

Comment: In the dataset ROE column contains values like '28.00%', '120.00%' etc... not a float value. So '>' operator doesnt work. Need to first typecast to float by removing last character. Unable to do that

Comment: i tried below code "missing.loc[float(missing.ROE[:-1])>100, 'ROE'] = np.nan". it throws an error "cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>"

Comment: I recommend replacing the first line with `missing['ROE'] = missing['ROE'].str.strip('%')`, and using `pd.to_numeric`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Series.mask`.  The following will update the dataframe `df` in place.

```
df.update(df.ROE.mask(pd.to_numeric(df.ROE.str[:-1]) > 100))
```